# Highchart is not defining angular 9

Tags: angular, highcharts

I want to create a pie chart with highcharts but I got errors in the console `Highchart is not defined`.

This is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
"@angular/common": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/core": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.2",
"@angular/router": "~8.1.2",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"highcharts": "^8.2.1",
"highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",
"rxjs": "~6.4.0",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1" }
```

This my component.ts:

```
import * as Highcharts from  'highcharts';

export class DrawPiechartComponent implements OnInit {
highcharts = Highcharts;
chartOptions: any;
ngOnInit() {
this.prepareLinechart(); }
prepareLinechart() {
this.chartOptions = {
  chart : {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type : 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  accessibility: {
    point: {
      valueSuffix: '%'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
      }
    }
  },
 
  series: [{
    name: 'Pie',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: this.historicalData
}] }
```

In the html :

```
<highcharts-chart *ngIf="chartOptions" [Highcharts]="highcharts" [options]="chartOptions"
  style="width: 100%; height: 400px; display: block;">
```

The module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DrawLinechartComponent } from './draw-linechart/draw- 
linechart.component';
import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';
import { DrawPiechartComponent } from './draw-piechart/draw- 
piechart.component';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
DrawLinechartComponent,
DrawPiechartComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,   
HighchartsChartModule
],
providers: [DataFromFormService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**PS : I have another component that uses highchart which draw a line chart and it works well ! May the problem is related to it ? ( because I imported the highchart 2 times in the piechart component and the linechart component )**

This is the other component :

```
import * as Highcharts from  'highcharts';
highcharts = Highcharts;
chartOptions: any;
 prepareLinechart() {
this.chartOptions = {
   chart: {
      type: 'line'
   },
   title: {
      text: '',
      style: {
         color: '#9E0E40',
         fontWeight: 'bold'
     }
   },

   legend: {   
      align: 'center',
   },
   
   xAxis: {
      categories: this.historicproducts
      title: {
         text: "Date",
         margin: 45
      },
      width:1100
   },
   yAxis: {
     
      title: {
         text: 'Data'
      }
   },
   series: [
      {
         name:"historics",
         data: this.products
     
      }]
};
and it has the same html
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What does your module ts look like?

Comment: @E.Maggini I add it to my post

Comment: Could you also post the component that IS working? Also have you tried comparing your approach against the demo in github repo and does that demo work as expected on your machine?

Comment: @E.Maggini edited my post again ! yes it works like the demo in the component Linechart but not in the component Piechart that's why I think maybe the problem is the import of highchart 2 times

Comment: You could always try to remove the import. Though this is unlikely the issue. Could could also try swapping chart options between components. If this changes which one fails it is possible there is something wrong with your options

Comment: Are you sure that you are using Highcharts 8.1.0? I copy, passed your config with some random data and it is working correctly with that version. 
Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-32en5m?file=src/app/app.component.ts

There is a reported bug in the 8.1.1+ that might throw "Highcharts is not defined" while working with the empty pie, however, in the 8.1.0 it is not a case.
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13710
If the error still persists in the 8.1.0 please reproduce the issue in an online editor so I can check what is not working.

Comment: @MateuszKornecki yes thank you it was a problem with version ! actually when I install highchart I used the cmd "npm install highcharts --save " then I modified manually in the package.json the version of highcharts to 8.1.0 but it doesn't work So the solution is to use the cmd "npm install highcharts@8.1.0 --save" and it works

Comment: Any update on this issue ? Facing same issue on the latest version 9.1.0 for bubble chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the version 8.2.1 of the highchart so the solution is to change the version `npm install highcharts@8.1.0 --save`